# Numpy array overwritten in nested function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, overwrite

The problem I have is that when I send an array (array "a" in code below) to a function ("summation" in code below), then assign it to another array (array "d" in code below), any change in elements of array "d" is reflected on array "a" as well.

```
from numpy import *

def summation(a,b):
    a_row = len(a[:,1])
    b_row=len(a[1,:])
    d = a
    for i in range(a_row):
        for j in range(a_col):
            d[i,j]=d[i,j]+b[i,j]
    return d

def define():
    a = array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])
    b = array([[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]])
    z=summation(a,b)
    print a
    print b
    print z

define()
```

So when I run this code, the output is:

```
[[12 14 16 18 20]
 [22 24 26 28 30]]
[[11 12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19 20]]
[[12 14 16 18 20]
 [22 24 26 28 30]]
```

I would like "a" to be untouched and does not change. Please help me if you have any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in function of numpy: `numpy.copy`:

```
d = numpy.copy(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning reference of a to d, since a list/in this case numpy array are mutable, any changes to d, will also affect values in a.

EDIT:- 
@EdChum thanks for the better way
Numpy has a builtin copy function, since a is already a numpy array,  you could use:-

```
d = a.copy()
```

@Old way which needs an additional import:-

```
import copy
d = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

instead of doing `d=a`

Comment: there is a `copy` method available for np arrays so `d=a.copy()` would work without importing copy